# AWS CodeBuild projects not running concurrently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have multiple different, independent AWS CodeBuild projects set up. All of them are using the aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0 image.

What I expect is for them to run concurrently, whenever a BitBucket webhook triggers them on PUSH. However, what happens is that one build from one build definition runs, whereas the others, belonging to different build definition projects are in QUEUED status, waiting for the first build to complete. Only then do they get the build environment provisioned.

I have also tried the ubuntu standard 5.0 runtime.

Is there a way to instruct CodeBuild to run different build projects in parallel, not waiting for each other to finish?

Comment: I thought codebuild runs concurrently by default. There is a quota per region per account though. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/limits.html. Are you hitting the 20 - 60 concurrent runs?

Comment: I am nowhere near the quota. I have around 10 build different projects in my region, and at most 5 are supposed to be run at the same time (depending on the activity of developers pushing their code).

I am not seeing 2 run at the same time, but rather 1 running, and the others in the QUEUED status.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope. Ended up migrating to github actions